# Reverse the sequence of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to reverse the sequence of an `int`-array. Here's my code which gives a truckload of errors.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int [] reverseArray(int []);

int main(){
    int arr[5] = {3,9,11,2,7};
    int arr2[5] = reverseArray(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
}

int [] reverseArray(int param[]){
    int s = sizeof(param)/sizeof(param[0]);
    int j = 0;
    int* a[s];
    for (int i = s ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a[j] = param[i];
        j++;    
    }
    return a;
}
```

I need to pass the modified array back to the main function. So please don't suggest me void functions that handles the output themselves.

Comment: **fyi**, there's also an [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) in the standard library.

Comment: They're two very different questions as I see.

Comment: @pepper_chico, I'm aware of that. But I'm trying to get the logic myself.

Comment: Don't return arrays from functions like that. C arrays are not your friend. Modifying `param` is sufficient to alter the original array. If you want arrays to behave like normal objects, use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: Printing the value of `s` ( in `int s = sizeof(param)/sizeof(param[0]);`) might give you a clue.

Comment: They are not two very different questions. your array decays when you pass it as a parameter. `sizeof(param)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Can someone please provide the correct implementation of the code.

Comment: @SoumasishGoswami the cppreference.com link that was provided has a "possible implementation" section that should work. Maybe you could try to understand what it is doing.

Comment: you need to allocate space for the array on the heap (e.g. malloc). You can't return a local array, as it will have gone out of scope when the function returns

Comment: @Paul I don't think "use malloc" is good advice here..

Comment: @NeilKirk given the constraints of the questioner their aren't really other options, since the OP is dead set against `std::vector` and specifically doesn't want to use output parameters.

Comment: @Paul or Neil can either of you modify my existing code and provide a working implementation, with a few words explaining why you did it that way.

Comment: @Paul Since he's using c++, I think the better advice is to use `std::array`. Its purpose is to be an array that can be passed/returned without issue, which it looks like OP wants.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "What is array decaying". Yeah, OP doesn't know about array decaying, but that is not the question nor the answer.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I assumed this was an assignment. If there's a need to actually reverse an array in production code, then yes, `std:vector` or something is a better choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `std::array` class which works more like you expect. The reverse function is able to take arrays of any size and type, provided the length is known at compile-time. I also fixed a bug in your reverse logic. It went out of bounds on the param array on the first iteration.

Live example here: http://ideone.com/UuUQ9c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template<class T, size_t N>
std::array<T, N> reverseArray(const std::array<T, N>& param)
{
    int j = 0;
    std::array<T, N> a;
    for (int i = N - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a[j] = param[i];
        j++;    
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {3,9,11,2,7};
    std::array<int, 5> arr2 = reverseArray<int, 5>(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, though I'd prefer `auto arr2 = reverseArray(arr);` to reduce maintenance if the length of `arr` ever changes.

Comment: @RedAlert Good comment. I wanted to keep it straight forward. The repetition of the template parameters is not the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ you can simplify your solution with:

```
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
    for(auto& e : v)
      cout << e << " ";
```

http://ideone.com/mDMSmZ

Comment: I don't want to use vectors, can you please implement the code using C-Style arrays.

Comment: @SoumasishGoswami vectors are just as fast as arrays most of the time, and they are less error prone. Why do you want to use arrays?

Comment: probably the teacher said to do so.

Comment: @ash teaching beginners arrays first is just bad teaching.

Comment: @TimSeguine I wouldn't necessarily agree. Either way, this smells like homework to me.

Comment: Guys, homework or not, thing is I need a correct implementation, with some explanation as to how arrays are passed between functions in C/C++. Great if you can provide that, if not, stop your time and mine.

Answer (score 1):

#### Without using the std library:

Using simply `int[]` type and without dynamic allocation you can't have it as return value, because the size of resulting `int[]` is unknown at compilation type. You can still do the following, obtaining the same result:

```
void reverse(const int a[], int size, int arr[]){
   int tmp, i;
   for (i=0; i < size; i++){
      arr[i]=a[i];
   }
   for (i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) {
      tmp = arr[size-i-1];
      arr[size-i-1] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = tmp;
   }
}

int main(){
   int size=5;
   int source[] = {3,9,11,2,7};
   int destination[size];
   reverse(source, size, destination);
}
```

#### Using the std library (recommended):

If available and if not in special conditions (e.g. some homework/assignment constraint ;) ) you should prefer std library algorithms:

```
int a[]= {...};
const int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int b[size];

std::reverse_copy(a, a+size, b);
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you modify the code to include it in a separate function and then call it in main. I'm confused more with that part of C.

Comment: there is also `std::array` in the standard library now, if the size is known at compile time.

Comment: The question explicitly says he doesn't want an inplace reverse (last paragraph)

Comment: @Paul you're right, modifying the answer accordingly...

Comment: @SoumasishGoswami I encapsulated it in a function, performing a deep copy (so you will have your original array untouched).

Comment: Why copy and then reverse? It's inefficient.

Comment: @NeilKirk agreed, but we're not searching for an optimized algorithm here...

Answer (score 1):

No such as thing return type `int[]`, because unknown size variable can't be located on stack.

Your options are:

```
const int* reverse(const int input[],size_t size){
   int* output = new int[size];//needed to be delete 
   ...
   return output;
}  

void reverse(int input_output[],size_t size){
   //use same array for input & output 
}  

void reverse(const int input[], int output[],size_t size){
   //get output as out parameter 
}
```

Best options if you ask me are the 2nd and the 3rd, use the 2nd if you can change the input, use the 3rd if you need both input and output.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply minimal changes to your code.  Here is something that worked:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int * reverseArray(int, int []);

int main(){

    int arr[5] = {3,9,11,2,7};
    int sz = sizeof ( arr ) / sizeof ( arr[0] );
    int * arr2 = reverseArray(sz, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr2[i] << endl;
    }


}

int * reverseArray(int s, int param[]){

    int j = 0;
    int * a = new int[s];
    for (int i = s - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a[j] = param[i];
        j++;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Explanation:

- The array is passed to function by pointer.  So, you cannot determine its size in there.  You will have to determine the size beforehand and pass the size with as a function parameter.
- The way you allocated array is local to the function.  You need to allocate dynamic memory to be able to pass it back.

Comment: What about the memory leak?

Comment: This code really helps, let me understand this right. So in the function reverseArray you're returning a pointer to the array a?

Comment: `a` points to an array allocated on the heap. A copy of this pointer is returned from the function. The pointer `a` and the array it points to are separate entities.

Comment: @NeilKirk just out of curiosity are we not supposed to delete all variables created using new

Comment: Yes that's why I discourage any code with `new` in it.

Comment: So is there any other way this can be done, without using <array> from STL. If we assume this was a C Program.

Comment: Any good ways with the constraints you specify? No.

Comment: @SoumasishGoswami, without using dynamic allocation quick answer: no. the best you can do is an input/output parameter as per my solution.

Comment: You could use `void reverseArray(int s, const int input[], int output[])` which would remove the need for dynamic memory.

Comment: Yes, this code does leak memory and I had noticed that when I wrote it.  However, as the code terminates quickly, I did not bother to add `delete`.  There are other things I would have liked to do, for example, using a single variable in the loop instead of `i` and `j` but I tried to stay close to OP's code.